# How can you reshape data in SAS while keeping data formats for further Excel export?

Tags: excel, sas, ods

I have a dataset in SAS that I want to export to Excel in a particular table. I want to do multiple operations on the data :

1. Reshape the data
2. Format data
3. Export to Excel

Here is a sample dataset.

```
data sample;
   input Product $ Year Metric1 Metric2 Metric3;
   datalines;
    A 2017 74 222 28895
    A 2018 45 235 15371
    B 2017 88 14 813
    B 2018 89 157 2304
    ;
```

What I ultimately want is the following.

[image]

Using `proc transpose` I can get the following, which is close but not perfect.

```
proc transpose data=Sample out=transposed name=Metrics;
by Product ;
id Year;
var Metric1 Metric2 Metric3;
run;
proc print data=transpose noobs; run;
```

[image: Goal]

The problem with this output is the formatting. I do not mind adding formatting only when exporting to Excel though, I just don't know how. So I guess my question is in two different parts :

1. Can I transpose my dataset `sample` keeping the format ?
2. Or can I add formatting to the `tranposed` dataset when exporting to Excel to obtain the format illustrated in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI9pk.png).

Comment: PROC REPORT can let you do conditional formatting. Use ODS EXCEL as your "export" method and you can use PROC REPORT to produce your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CALL DEFINE() in PROC REPORT to set display properties.  Use ODS EXCEL to route the report to an Excel file.  I will use the FORMAT attribute in this example, but you probable want to use the STYLE attribute to effect how Excel will display the values.

```
data sample;
   input Product $ Year Metric1 Metric2 Metric3;
   metric1=metric1/100;
datalines;
A 2017 74 222 28895
A 2018 45 235 15371
B 2017 88 14 813
B 2018 89 157 2304
;

proc transpose data=sample out=want ;
  by product year;
  var metric1-metric3 ;
run;

proc report data=want nofs headline ;
column product _name_ col1,year ;
define product / group;
define _name_ / group 'Metric';
define year/across ' ';
define col1/sum ' ';
compute col1 ;
  if (_name_='Metric1') then call define(_col_,'format','percent.');
  if (_name_='Metric2') then call define(_col_,'format','dollar.');
  if (_name_='Metric3') then call define(_col_,'format','comma.');
endcomp;
run;
```

Output:

```
  Product   Metric         2017       2018
  ----------------------------------------
  A         Metric1        74%        45%
            Metric2        $222       $235
            Metric3      28,895     15,371
  B         Metric1        88%        89%
            Metric2         $14       $157
            Metric3         813      2,304
```